# selenium-webdriver idles until mouse is moved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium

I am writing test automation using Selenium / Protractor / Jasmine for a web app written with Angular.  I am running the test inside VirtualBox (Host OS: Windows 8, Guest OS: Ubuntu 15.04).  So far, the test is very basic (the onPrepare function logs in and waits for the app to load, the first test checks to see whether the loaded page has the right title.

The app is successfully loading and logging in.  The problem is, once this happens, the test does not proceed until the mouse is moved, and only while the mouse is over the content area of the browser window.

1) If I don't move the mouse at all, I eventually get the error: "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."

2) If I move the mouse over other windows, or over non-content areas of the browser window (window border, address bar, etc), I get the same behavior.

3) As soon as I move the mouse over the content area of the browser window, the test proceeds immediately.

I have given my test code to a coworker who has run it on a Mac, and he did not have this problem.  This implies to me that it is an issue caused by running inside VirtualBox, but I am not 100% sure that is the case.

I have tried searching through Google and other stackoverflow posts, to see if I could find other reports of this kind of behavior, but found nothing.  I also tried changing the default timeouts within jasmine and protractor:
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 250000
allScriptsTimeout: 300000
getPageTimeout: 300000
, but this had no effect.

As this is my first question asked on stackoverflow, if there is more information generally given for this kind of question, please let me know and I will add it.

Comment: Can you also add the code which is trying to make this call? You might need to check why it is attempting the async call.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't (private, company-owned code and all).

Comment: It turns out there was something polling timeout repeatedly, which was causing this.  Problem solved.

Comment: @Phil When you say "polling timeout repeatedly", do you mean something leveraging `$timeout` was refreshing the page out from underneath you? Or was something messing with the timeout values in your test stack? Thanks

Comment: @anjunatl the former.  I don't think it was exactly refreshing the page, but was using $timeout in a way that made Protractor think the page wasn't ready.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did not find a reason or a definitive solution. I made a paleative solution, move the mouse after the click action.

```
browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 50, y: 0}).perform ();
```

After that the test works normally.