# Selenium idles until I move mouse

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, testng

Have a Selenium (or more likely a webpage) issue that's driving me nuts. The page will only continue execution if I move the mouse physically. I have tried everything from attempting to simulate hover, clicks, keyboard presses etc to Thread.sleeps. Nothing resolves it, but rest assured a singular move of the mouse is enough to get it going again (this makes me think it's a webpage issue). If I don't move the mouse, or interact with the page physically in some way, it will idle infinitely.

Through troubleshooting, it seems every single interaction with that page (whether it's an explicit wait, element click or driver.getAttribute) is enough for it to idle once, after that all interactions are performed as expected.

The webpage is angular, and the elements I'm typically interacting with are input and button elements residing inside a mat-card element.
When the page loads for the first time, a query is ran to determine the value/state of the elements. So if the values in the database are a certain type, that will trigger some buttons to be enabled, and the input elements to have different values etc. I believe the way the page loads may be causing this issue.
Only this webpage will cause this issue, the rest of the site performs as expected.

I have an implicit wait timeout of only 5 seconds, so if it's not triggering that and stopping execution, it's not an element visibility issue.

I have only seen one example of this on the web, and that's with a guy using protractor here: [selenium-webdriver idles until mouse is moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000139/selenium-webdriver-idles-until-mouse-is-moved)

If anyone has any idea what might be causing this beyond what I've attempted it'd be appreciated a lot, even if it's a confirmation that there's not much I can do but talk to the devs about the issue and see if it's on their side etc.

Comment: is there an iframe in that page ?

Comment: No, doesn't appear to be any iframes unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this with 'forcing' a mouse movement without any waits immediately after the driver.get request to the page. If I add waits, it'll have the same idling issue, but with this, it works 98% of the time. Much better than it was. I can't explain why I need to do this, but all I know is 100% it's the way the page loads.

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-nav-bar/mat-toolbar/div/mat-icon")));
    action.perform();
    action.moveByOffset(15,15);
    action.perform();
```

On further testing, it seems to hang if I move 'desktops' within Windows 10 and almost certainly rules out that this will work in headless. Still on the lookout for a real solution as the above is a quick and dirty 'fix'